# Is the UV editing wrong or shading and texturing?

Tags: shaders

The textures on some different keys of the keyboard are wrapped some other keys are sideways.

I'm new to Blender to can't figure out this thing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your unwrap must be incorrect, what you can do is select all the side faces of one key then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Normal*:

[image]

Then select a view (side view for example) and press <kbd>U</kbd> *(Unwrap) > Project from View*:

[image]

And put the UVs somewhere over your image in the *Image Editor*, so that no letter will appear:

[image]